# Hard link as destination of cp and rsync

Tags: files, rsync, cp, file-copy, hard-link

Where do I find documentation of behavior of `cp` and `rsync` commands when the destination path shares the inode with another path? In other words, when I do

```
$ cp [options] src dest
$ rsync [options] src dest
```

and when there is `dest2` that is a hard link to the same inode as `dest`, do these commands modify the content at this inode [Let's call it behavior (i)], or do they create a new inode, fill this inode with the content of src, and link dest to the new inode [behavior (ii)]?

In the case of behavior (i), I will see the results of `cp` and `rsync` by accessing `dest2`, whereas I will not see them in the case of behavior (ii).

I observed that the behavior depends on the options. In particular, with `-a` option, both `cp` and `rsync` took behavior (ii) as far as I experimented. [`cp` without any option took behavior (i).] I would like to know if this is guaranteed, and I wish someone to kindly point to documentation. Or, I would appreciate it if someone could kindly suggest some words or phrases to search for.

Below are my experiment.
First, I create a test sample:

```
$ ls 
work
$ ls -li work/
total 12
23227072 -rw-rw-r-- 1 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:52 file000.txt
23227071 -rw-rw-r-- 1 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:52 file001.txt
23227073 -rw-rw-r-- 1 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:52 file002.txt
$ cat work/file000.txt 
This is file000.
$ cat work/file001.txt 
This is file001.
$ cat work/file002.txt 
This is file002.
```

```
$ cp -r work backup
$ ls
backup  work
$ ls -li backup/
total 12
23227087 -rw-rw-r-- 1 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file000.txt
23227065 -rw-rw-r-- 1 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file001.txt
23227092 -rw-rw-r-- 1 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file002.txt
$ cat backup/file000.txt 
This is file000.
$ cat backup/file001.txt 
This is file001.
$ cat backup/file002.txt 
This is file002.
$
```

```
$ cp -al backup backupOld
$ ls
backup  backupOld  work
$ ls -li backupOld/
total 12
23227087 -rw-rw-r-- 2 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file000.txt
23227065 -rw-rw-r-- 2 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file001.txt
23227092 -rw-rw-r-- 2 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file002.txt
$ cat backupOld/file000.txt 
This is file000.
$ cat backupOld/file001.txt 
This is file001.
$ cat backupOld/file002.txt 
This is file002.
$
```

Thus far, I created files under `backupOld` as hard links to the files of the same name under `backup`.
Now, I modify files under `work` and copy them to `backup` by `cp`, `cp -a`, and `rsync -a`.

```
$ echo "Hello work 000." >> work/file000.txt 
$ echo "Hello work 001." >> work/file001.txt 
$ echo "Hello work 002." >> work/file002.txt 
$ cat work/file000.txt 
This is file000.
Hello work 000.
$ cat work/file001.txt 
This is file001.
Hello work 001.
$ cat work/file002.txt 
This is file002.
Hello work 002.
$
```

```
$ cat backup/file000.txt 
This is file000.
$ cat backup/file001.txt 
This is file001.
$ cat backup/file002.txt 
This is file002.
$ cat backupOld/file000.txt 
This is file000.
$ cat backupOld/file001.txt 
This is file001.
$ cat backupOld/file002.txt 
This is file002.
$
```

```
$ ls -li work/
total 12
23227072 -rw-rw-r-- 1 norio norio 33 Oct 19 00:57 file000.txt
23227071 -rw-rw-r-- 1 norio norio 33 Oct 19 00:57 file001.txt
23227073 -rw-rw-r-- 1 norio norio 33 Oct 19 00:57 file002.txt
$ ls -li backup/
total 12
23227087 -rw-rw-r-- 2 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file000.txt
23227065 -rw-rw-r-- 2 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file001.txt
23227092 -rw-rw-r-- 2 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file002.txt
$ ls -li backupOld/
total 12
23227087 -rw-rw-r-- 2 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file000.txt
23227065 -rw-rw-r-- 2 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file001.txt
23227092 -rw-rw-r-- 2 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file002.txt
$
```

```
$ cp work/file000.txt  backup
$ cp -a work/file001.txt  backup
$ rsync -a work/file002.txt  backup
$ 
$ ls -li backup
total 12
23227087 -rw-rw-r-- 2 norio norio 33 Oct 19 01:00 file000.txt
23227094 -rw-rw-r-- 1 norio norio 33 Oct 19 00:57 file001.txt
23227095 -rw-rw-r-- 1 norio norio 33 Oct 19 00:57 file002.txt
$ 
$ ls -li backupOld
total 12
23227087 -rw-rw-r-- 2 norio norio 33 Oct 19 01:00 file000.txt
23227065 -rw-rw-r-- 1 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file001.txt
23227092 -rw-rw-r-- 1 norio norio 17 Oct 19 00:53 file002.txt
$
```

`cp` overwrote the content of inode `23227087` shared by `backup/file000.txt` and `backupOld/file000.txt`, whereas `cp -a` and `rsync -a` created new inodes for `backup/file001.txt` and `backup/file002.txt`, respectively, to hold the new contents copied from `work/file001.txt` and `work/file002.txt`.

```
$ cat backup/file000.txt 
This is file000.
Hello work 000.
$ cat backup/file001.txt 
This is file001.
Hello work 001.
$ cat backup/file002.txt 
This is file002.
Hello work 002.
$ cat backupOld/file000.txt 
This is file000.
Hello work 000.
$ cat backupOld/file001.txt 
This is file001.
$ cat backupOld/file002.txt 
This is file002.
$
```

Comment: This is as expected, see also: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62355054/copy-and-moves-command-effect-on-inode) and [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html). Also `info cp` gives some more information.

Comment: I haven't read your test cases, but for rsync you might want to checkout `--inplace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cp`’s behaviour is [specificied by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html). `-a` isn’t specified by POSIX, but it implies `-R` which is. When copying a single file, without `-R`, and the target exists,

> A file descriptor for *dest_file* shall be obtained by performing actions equivalent to the [*open*()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) function defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2017 called using *dest_file* as the *path* argument, and the bitwise-inclusive OR of O_WRONLY and O_TRUNC as the *oflag* argument.

Thus the target is opened, truncated, and its contents replaced with those of the source; the inode doesn’t change, and any hard linked file is affected.

With `-R`,

> The *dest_file* shall be created with the same file type as *source_file*.

A new file is created.

`rsync`’s behaviour is documented in the description of the `--inplace` option (see [`man rsync`](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1)):

> This option changes how rsync transfers a file when its data needs to be updated: instead of the default method of
> creating a new copy of the file and moving it into place when it is complete, rsync  instead  writes  the  updated
> data directly to the destination file.

Thus by default, `rsync` creates new files instead of updating existing ones.